# How to override method with inherited class in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, inheritance, abstraction

I am exploring and actively using generics in production with Kotlin.

Kotlin + generics is a big puzzle for me, so maybe you can explain and help me understand how it works here, compared to Java.

I have class `AbstracApiClient` (not really abstract)

```
class AbstracApiClient {
  
  open protected fun makeRequest(requestBuilder: AbstractRequestBuilder) {
    // ... 
  }
}
```

`AbstractRequestBuilder` (not really abstract):

```
open class AbstractRequestBuilder {
  ...
}
```

`ConcreteApiClient` that inherits `AbstractApiClient` that should override makeRequest with `ConcreteRequestBuilder` inherited from `AbstractRequestBuilder`:

```
class ConcreteApiClient: AbstractApiClient() {
  
  protected override fun makeRequest(requestBuilder: ConcreteRequestBuilder) {
    // ... 
  }
}

class ConcreteRequestBuilder: AbstractRequestBuilder()
```

As I would have more concrete API clients. I would like to make an abstraction that I can pass inherited concrete requests builders and override `make requests method.

1. I tried using it as it is but wouldn't work
2. I tried this notation `protected open fun <R: ApiRequestBuilder> make request(request builder: R)` but it won't match overriding function which I want it to be: `protected override fun make request(request builder: ConcreteRequestBuilder)`

What other options do I have? Am I missing something here?

**Note:** I cannot use `interface` or `abstract classes` in this scenario, so ideally I would like to find a way with inheritance and functions overriding.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what doesn't work with the current approach without generics? What error do you get / with which code?

Comment: The overriding method doesn't work in both scenarios, so method `protected override fun makeRequest(requestBuilder: ConcreteRequestBuilder)` doesn't get matched by any of the 2 specified methods I used.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I will try to explain in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override a method with more specific argument types, because it breaks [Liskov's substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle):

```kotlin
val client: AbstractApiClient = ConcreteApiClient()

client.makeRequest(AbstractRequestBuilder())
```

As you can see above, the `ConreteApiClient` implementation has to be able to handle all possible inputs of the parent class, because it could be accessed through the parent class's API.

To do what you want, you need to restrict the parent class itself via generics:

```kotlin
open class AbstractApiClient<R : AbstractRequestBuilder> {
  
  open protected fun makeRequest(requestBuilder: R) {
    // ... 
  }
}

class ConcreteApiClient: AbstractApiClient<ConcreteRequestBuilder>() {
  
  protected override fun makeRequest(requestBuilder: ConcreteRequestBuilder) {
    // ... 
  }
}
```

This way, any instance of `AbstractApiClient<R>` has to show which type of request builder it accepts (in the type argument). It prevents the above issue because now the parent type also carries information:

```kotlin
// doesn't compile
val client: AbstractApiClient<AbstractRequestBuilder> = ConcreteApiClient() 

// this compiles
val client: AbstractApiClient<ConcreteRequestBuilder> = ConcreteApiClient()
```

> I tried this notation protected open fun <R: ApiRequestBuilder> make request(request builder: R)

Now regarding this attempt, it doesn't work because if you make the *method* generic (not the *class*) it means every implementation of the method has to handle *all* kinds of `R` (NOT one `R` per implementation). Putting the generic on the class allows to specify the generic argument once per instance of the class.

Comment: Thx, I tried something similar but I think stopped halfway. Am I correct that it is allowed in Java, so Java is allowed to break Liskov's principle?

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi Java doesn't allow to override methods with more concrete parameter types either. If you try to annotate the method with `@Override` it should not compile.

Comment: However Java does break a few things along those lines when it comes to generics because it allows [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/1540818). Java's generics are broken because of this